# Determine the number of positive integers that share at least one of the numbers

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

**The question:**

Determine the number of positive integers that divide at least one of the numbers $3680$ and $100$.

**The answer:**

We have that $3680 = 2^5\cdot5\cdot23$ and $100 = 2^2\cdot5^2$

The number of positive integers dividing $3680$ is therefore $6\cdot2\cdot2$, the number of positive integers dividing $100$ is $3\cdot3$, and the number of positive numbers that divide both $3680$ and $100$ is $3\cdot2$. The number sought is thus $24 + 9 − 6 = 27$

**What I need help with**

I don't understand the resesing for *dividing $3680$ is therefore $6\cdot2\cdot2$* and *dividing $100$ is $3\cdot3$*

Comment: The number of divisors of $p_1^{m_1}p_2^{m_2}\cdots p_t^{m_t}$ is $(m_1+1)(m_2+1)\cdots(m_t+1)$.

Comment: Any positive integer factor of $3680$ must be equal to $2^a{\,\cdot\,}5^b{\,\cdot\,}23^c$ for some choice of integer exponents $a,b,c$ with $0\le a\le 5,\;0\le b\le 1,\;0\le c\le 1$. Thus there are $6$ choices for $a$, $2$ choices for $b$, and $2$ choices for $c$, so $6{\,\cdot\,}2{\,\cdot\,}2=24$ possible triples $a,b,c$.

Comment: ah ok. thanks yall for your answers I and the duplicate answers were good as well thanks!

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=2JM2oImb9Qg